# Obtain 1 Hour Before Without Minutes/Seconds

Tags: php, datetime

I need to fetch 1 hour before of current date regardless of minutes and seconds of execution time.

What I'm doing is to create a `DateTime()` object and use `sub(new DateInterval('PT1H')` but the problem is, when I run my code in between 00:00 - 00:59 on December 28th, it gives me 23:00 of December 28th instead of 23:00 December 27th.

My code;

```
$dc_date = new DateTime();
$dc_date->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
$dc_date->setTime($dc_date->format('G'), 0);
```

What should be the optimal solution to fetch 1 hour before for sample scenario?

```
Execute time between: XX:00:00 - XX:59:59 (XX is 0-23)
Desired output: XX-1:00:00
```

Comment: `$dc_date = (new \DateTime())->modify('-1 hour');`

Comment: @miken32 Thank you miken, I still don't understand why my code acts weird, but your solution is way simpler which I will definitely use it.

Comment: As to why simple math is problematic, consider this example: https://3v4l.org/lL2f9